# Aggregating multiple time series to match MODIS timestep in R

Tags: r, modis, time-series, aggregate

I have multiple time series data for precipitation and evapotranspiration that are irregularly spaced.  All but one of the datasets are daily products, but sadly one is a MODIS product that has irregular spacing (8 days most of the time, 5-6 days at the end of the year depending on whether it's a leap year).  But I need all products to match the 8 day temporal resolution of the MODIS product.  For instance:

```
dates        prod1     prod2
             (daily)   (variable)
10-01-2001   1          NA
10-02-2001   1          NA
10-03-2001   1          NA
10-04-2001   1          NA
10-05-2001   1          NA
10-06-2001   1          NA
10-07-2001   1          NA
10-08-2001   1          8
```

What I am looking for is a way to consistently get the aggregate of product 1 to match prod2, but prod2 has a variable number of NAs depending on the period.

Obviously, rollapply and aggregate are out because I don't have consistent spacing. Is there another way to do this without a very complicated ifelse statement/mutate combination?

Comment: Which software are you working with?

Comment: R sorry will add that to the thread

Comment: adding a tag is even more important. Did so for you.